# SQL joining Thread with post issue how would you solve it

Tags: sql

I need help

```
$sql = "SELECT  
                topics.topic_id,
                topics.topic_subject,
                topics.topic_date,
                topics.topic_cat,
                topics.topic_by,
                topics.topic_open_close,
                topics.topic_pin
            FROM
                topics
                LEFT JOIN posts ON topics.topic_id = posts.post_topic_id
            WHERE
                topics.topic_cat = '". $_GET['id']."' AND topics.topic_pin = '0' ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC;
```

my SQL is ORDERING the Topics base on post date. the problem I'm having is that when I reply more than 1 time, lets say 3 replies, it shows 3 of the same threads.

the purpose I'm trying to archive with this Query is to bump up the thread by posting base on post_date. its doing the job. It's its just showing more than one thread.

how would you guys get write this Query to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are joining the `posts` table even thought you are not displaying some of its columns. But if you want to display 1 topic based on the latest `post date`, you can join the `max(post_date)` via subquery.

```
SELECT  
    topics.topic_id,
    topics.topic_subject,
    topics.topic_date,
    topics.topic_cat,
    topics.topic_by,
    topics.topic_open_close,
    topics.topic_pin
FROM topics
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT max(post_date) post_date, post_topic_id FROM posts GROUP BY post_topic_id) t2 ON topics.topic_id = t2.post_topic_id
WHERE
    topics.topic_cat = '". $_GET['id']."' AND topics.topic_pin = '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the long way. I needed to get it done. My plan was to make it short.
with a SQL Query.

I have a functions.php folder to run all my functions thru out the project.
so i created a function inside the functions.php to run all query and not having to repeat myself.
examp:

```
function query($sql, $conn){
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(!$result){
    echo 'There is a Error in the SQL '. mysqli_error($conn); 
}else{
return $result;
}
}
```

I added a column on Topics called "Topic_last_post_date". Every time someone post if the Query to post the post goes successfully it will execute the query to update the "Topic_last_post_date" on the assigned topic.

```
    //posting Query ect ect..
if(!$result_of_query){
echo'Error';
}else{
$stamp_post_date_on_Topic = query("UPDATE topics SET topic_last_post_date = NOW() WHERE topic_id='".$topicid."' ", $conn);}
```

then I ended using the this query to display the topic DESC = Descending starting from the last to "Topic_last_post_date" posted.

```
    $sql = "SELECT  
                topic_id,
                topic_subject,
                topic_date,
                topic_cat,
                topic_by,
                topic_open_close,
                topic_pin,
                topic_last_post_date
            FROM
                topics
            WHERE
                topic_cat = '". $_GET['id']."' AND topic_pin = '0' ORDER BY topic_last_post_date DESC LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$no_of_records_per_page." ";
```

I hope it help someone! thanks guys